# How to use the Device's Default Font in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fonts

I opened a *Java **native Android** app* and a ***Flutter*** Android app on the same device and took screenshots of both of the applications:

[image: Screenshots of the Java (left) and Flutter (right) applications]

As you can see, the fonts are they are using to display their text are different.
Both applications were run using the Samsung Galaxy S5 *Choco Cooky default theme*.

The **Java native app adapts** and displays the custom Samsung Galaxy font, whereas the **Flutter app does not adjust fonts**.

How can I configure my Flutter app to use the device's default font?

Comment: Flutter doesn't use the OEM widgets, so I guess this is not possible until you find some hack to do this.

Comment: you can use the custom fonts instead.

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana ok man, thanks.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-io/why-flutter-doesnt-use-oem-widgets-94746e812510

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `PlatformChannels` for the `TextView` and access this Android `TextView` into your Flutter Application.
And Use it instead of the `Text` widget of the Flutter.

Check out this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter, default font on Android is Roboto, and on iOS is .SF UI Pro and .SF UI Text.

> check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56339147/1776125

on iOS this is OK, but on android there are lots of ROMs with different default font family.

In order to get the device default font family, I wrote a platform channel on Android, here is the code to get device default font family:

```
private String getDefaultFont() {
        File configFilename = new File("/system/etc/system_fonts.xml");
        // sans-serif is the default font family name in Android SDK, check out the code in Typeface.java
        String defaultFontName = "sans-serif";

        try {
            FileInputStream fontsIn = new FileInputStream(configFilename);
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(fontsIn, null);
            boolean done = false;
            boolean getTheText = false;
            int eventType;
            while (!done) {
                eventType = parser.next();
                if (eventType == parser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                    getTheText = true;
                }
                if (eventType == parser.TEXT && getTheText) {
                    // first name
                    defaultFontName = parser.getText();
                    done = true;
                }
                if (eventType == parser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println("Didn't create default family (most likely, non-Minikin build)");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("GetDefaultFont: config file Not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("GetDefaultFont: IO exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            System.err.println("getDefaultFont: XML parse exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return defaultFontName;
    }
```

Comment: FileNotFoundException on Galaxy S10