# Text styles missing from CupertinoTextThemeData

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

According to Flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTextThemeData-class.html), the CupertinoTextThemeData has the following styles:

- **navActionTextStyle**: The TextStyle of interactive text content in navigation bars.
- **navLargeTitleTextStyle**: The TextStyle of large titles in sliver navigation bars.
- **navTitleTextStyle**: The TextStyle of titles in standard navigation bars.
- **pickerTextStyle** : The TextStyle of pickers.
- **tabLabelTextStyle**: The TextStyle of unselected tabs.
- **textStyle**: The TextStyle of general text content for Cupertino widgets.

However, Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) lists the following styles: **Large Title**, **Title 1**, **Title 2**, **Title 3**, **Headline**, **Body**, **Callout**, **Subhead**, **Footnote**, **Caption 1**, **Caption 2**.

Shouldn't these styles be defined in the CupertinoTextThemeData?  Are these defined somewhere else?

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can access them like this:

CupertinoTheme.of(context).textTheme.navLargeTitleTextStyle

Comment: Yes, @Pulkit, the Large Title can be accessed this way.  However, most of the other styles mentioned in Apple's docs are not available in this way.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56339147/14214312)  this page includes all the fonts available for CupertinoApp