# How to Set Different fonts for different locales in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to set different fonts for different `locals`? English font is the default for my app, but I need a different font for my Arabic `locale`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use Locale and Theme

This problem requires two things:

- Getting the system locale
- Providing a `Theme` with correct values depending on locale.

The locale can easily be retrieved by calling `window.locale` from `dart:ui`.
There is an quite [in-depth stack overflow post on locale here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923906/how-to-get-timezone-language-and-county-id-in-flutter-by-the-location-of-device) if you need more information on the locale aspects.

Based upon the locale, we set the `fontFamily` property on the `ThemeData` to the desired font defined in our pubspec.yaml file. ([instructions on adding a custom font are here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts))

### Example

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  VoidCallback rebuildOnLocaleChange() => () => setState(() {});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Retrieve locale from the system information.
    Locale myLocale = window.locale;
    PlatformDispatcher.instance.onLocaleChanged = rebuildOnLocaleChange();

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        // If language is english - we use the default font which is a sans-serif roboto font
        // If not, we use the serif roboto font, must be added in asset and pubspec.yaml to work.
        // TODO: replace the languageCode check with what you need.
        fontFamily: myLocale.languageCode == "en" ? null : "RobotoSerif",
      ),
      home: const AppScreen(),
    );
  }
}

// Just a simple screen with a text updating when the locale changes.
class AppScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Test",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

main() => runApp(const App());
```

Pictures below shows the Theme is set with the default font when the languageCode is "en" (left) and the custom font for other locales (right).

[image: Default font]
[image: Custom font]

Comment: Oh thanks you made it look very simple. That's what I wanted....

Comment: what is the null, and why else is Roboto, but if the condition is true then null?

Comment: In ThemeData, fontFamily is optional, this means if not specified (or set to null), we see in the implementation of ThemeData (and Flutter's material\typography.dart file) that it will default to a font specific to the app's TargetPlatform. For android: a sans-serif variant of roboto. For iOS: a San Francisco font. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860153/what-is-the-default-font-family-of-a-flutter-app .

When your phone's language is set to english, we use the default font, otherwise if the language is something else we use the font we provided in the pubspec file "RobotoSerif".

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for device locale changes and change the font-family respectively.

Comment: That's what OP is asking. You should add sample code for what you are saying. Otherwise, your answer isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is 'fontFamilyFallback' property which takes a list of strings (Font names)
Example:

```
ThemeData(
 fontFamily: 'RobotoSerif',
 fontFamilyFallback: ['Urbanist'],
 ...
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).