# How to use the device font in all app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I opened a Java native Android app and a Flutter Android app on the same device , the font of the native like default phone font .. like in the next screen..

[This screens from same problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zijq.png)

I tried solve of this problem here but ..

- this make native widget not get the font of phone !
- it's old and not work with me

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51913485/how-to-use-the-devices-default-font-in-flutter

Comment: Not work because it very old